# spotfire: How to write blob to database with parameterized informaion links?

Tags: spotfire

I'm trying to write some graphs i've generated in R back to our Oracle 11g database using parameterized information links but I keep coming up against the same error:

```
Failed to execute data source query for data source "FITS_GRAPH".
at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataSourceConnection.ExecuteQuery2()
at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.OnDemand.InformationLinkFunctionExecutor.SetOutputResult(DataSource dataSource, DataFunctionInvocation invocation, Boolean isEmpty)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.OnDemand.InformationLinkFunctionExecutor.<ExecuteFunction>d__0.MoveNext()
at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataFunctions.DataFunctionExecutorService.<ExecuteFunction>d__6.MoveNext()
```

I am generating the graphs in Open source R with ggplot, and saving them as binaries with the following commands:

```
tmpPlot <- ggplot(x, aes(x = LogConc, y = Normalized))
ggsave(name, plot = tmpPlot, units = 'cm', device = 'png', width = 15, height = 15, dpi = 300)
img=readBin(file(name, open="rb"), what="raw", n=(file.info(name)$size))
```

The graphs need to be loaded into the database as blobs because our reporting software expects to find them this way.

I have happily managed to get these graphs to return as a column in spotfire. However if I try use that column to feed into an information link parameter I get the above error.

I've tried creating using the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE fits_graph_insert (
    experiment_id   IN fits_graph."EXPERIMENT_ID"%TYPE,
    sample_id       IN fits_graph."SAMPLE_ID"%TYPE,
    replicate_id    IN fits_graph."REPLICATE_ID"%TYPE,
    image           IN fits_graph."IMAGE"%TYPE
)
    IS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO fits_graph (
        "EXPERIMENT_ID",
        "SAMPLE_ID",
        "REPLICATE_ID",
        "IMAGE"
    ) VALUES (
        experiment_id,
        sample_id,
        replicate_id,
        image
    );

    COMMIT;
END fits_graph_insert;
```

Or adding the following as a Pre-update in the information link:

```
INSERT INTO FITS_GRAPH (
    "EXPERIMENT_ID",             
    "SAMPLE_ID",           
    "REPLICATE_ID",
    "IMAGE"
    )
  VALUES (
    ?input_exp_id,             
    ?input_sample_id,           
    ?input_rep_id,
    ?input_image
    )
```

In either case if I don't include the image/blob the update runs fine.

Does anyone know if there is a way to write this data back to the db without hitting this error.

I've also tried converting to a `base64` encoded string however it comes out much too long to be written into a `VARCHAR2` field.

Any ideas or input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: not sure I have an answer for you, but have you tried executing the query in raw SQL? maybe there is a character encoding or datatype issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to encode the image as a base64 string then upload that into a CLOB field instead of a VARCHAR2 field.